# Replace a character in string using java

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to replace a character in a string using java. I tried to use replace function in string class but it's not working.

Need to remove the double quote beside Public Sector which is given below

```
null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתב\"ג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100
```

Could anyone help me to get possible solution for this.

code:

```
String csv = "null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתב\\\"ג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100";
    csv = csv.replace("\"", "");

    System.out.println(csv);
```

Comment: show your code and expected output

Comment: String csv="null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתב\\\"ג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100";
  csv=csv.replace("\"\\", "");
  System.out.println(csv);

Comment: u tried to replace " & \. what u need. only remove " ?

Comment: only to remove "( double quote ) beside the public sector

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
String csv = "null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתב\\\"ג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100";

    csv = csv.replace("\"", "").replace("\\","");
        System.out.println(csv);
```

Output:

```
null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתבג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String csv = "null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתב\\\"ג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100";

        csv = csv.replace("\"","");

        System.out.println(csv);
```

This code is working fine if you want to remove that quote sign

output is:

```
null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתב\ג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100
```

and if you want to remove both (" & //) then

```
String csv = "null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתב\\\"ג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100";

    csv = csv.replace("\"", "").replace("\\","");
        System.out.println(csv);
```

output :

```
null,לוד נמל תעופה,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,Public Sector,נתבג,XX400017791,,2,false,400017791,null,Account Register,null,null,11688,ISRAEL AIRPORTS AUTHORITY,null,2019-08-21T09:11:25,null,false,UKIIMEA,null,null,70100
```